# Cannot read property toLowerCase of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, I am working on an audio part where I fetch my words from a JSON file and when I show them on my front-end it should `onclick` on the audio button fetch the word from the server and create the audio... But I keep on getting `Cannot read property toLowerCase of undefined` and I cannot seem to find the error.

let's start with the variables I declared:

```
var MEDIAARRAY;
var WORDS;
var audioArray;
var audio = new Audio();
var LANGUAGE;
var SOUNDARRAY;
```

The piece of code (I took over the code given as answer and it helped me a bit further so I decided to edit the question with the code I have right now).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
getFileArray();
});

$(document).on("click", ".sound", function () {

getFileArray("SomeLanguage");               

 var foundID = MEDIAARRAY.audio.lowercase.indexOf($(this).parent().find('.exerciseWord').val().toLowerCase() + '.mp3');
var currentVal = $(this).parent().find('.fa-volume-up');
  if (foundID > -1) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = 'TheServerURL' + MEDIAARRAY.audio.path + MEDIAARRAY.audio.files[foundID] + '';
audio.play();
}
 });
```

The line where the error occurs:

```
var foundID =  MEDIAARRAY.audio.lowercase.indexOf($(this).parent().find('.exerciseWord').val().toLowerCase() + '.mp3');
```

The button where the class `sound` is appended to:

```
function getAudioForWords() {
 var audioBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'sound btn btn-primary'
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>');
return audioBtn;
}
```

the code where class `exerciseWord` gets append to:

```
    var wordCol = $('<div>', {
        class: 'col-md-9 ExerciseWordFontSize exerciseWord',
        'id': 'wordInput[' + ID123 + ']', 
        text: exercise.word
      });
```

and the piece of code that gets the fileArray, but most likely will be useless for you to inspect, but it was related to my code so... yeah.

```
function getFileArray(param)
{

var request = {
    language: param
};

$.ajax(
{
    url: "TheServerURL",
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    data: request,
    dataType: 'json',
}).done(function (response)
{
    console.log(response)
    MEDIAARRAY = response;
    audioArray = response.audio;
    console.log(audioArray);

  });
}
```

Comment: What does  console.log(response) prints ?

Comment: nothing... I tried console.log stuff, but it all looks good (or bad) in my console.log

Comment: Tried that one aswell, I did notice one thing tho: It gives the same error in my CMS side. however: When I change the language selector, it doesn't give the error anymore and it does play the sound. But when I don't change the language selector it throws in the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error states varialble MEDIAARRAY remains uninitialized somewhere in your code flow. See if following takes you close to the resolution

1. You have not mentioned at what point getFileArray function is called. Call to getFileArray function is critical because that is when MEDIAARRAY is assigned value.
2. Ensure getFileArray is called before you access any propery of MEDIAARRAY.
3. Ensure your API always returns object which contains audio property.

Example,

```
$(document).on("click", ".sound", function () {

//Ensure you supply parameter value to your function(i.e. value of the element you take user input from)
getFileArray("SomeLanguage");               

var foundID = MEDIAARRAY.audio.lowercase.indexOf($(this).parent().find('.exerciseWord').val().toLowerCase() + '.mp3');
var currentVal = $(this).parent().find('.fa-volume-up');
if (foundID > -1) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = 'TheServerURL' + MEDIAARRAY.audio.path + MEDIAARRAY.audio.files[foundID] + '';
    audio.play();
}
});
```

Comment: Oke, something did happen when I mentioned getFileArray, it now fetches everything but gives me back the response "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"